# Running Lua Code on the Mac?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, script

Hey, all.  This is a question that seems painfully obvious and not worth asking all of you, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to run `lua` code on the mac.  I have a folder full of `.lua` files that should run to make a simple command-line compression program, and I made sure to install `lua` using homebrew, so I don't know what I am still missing.

I hope someone knows how to do this, as I can't find anything online to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Now you've installed lua with Homebrew, you can now use the `lua` command:

```
lua /path/to/file.lua
```

Comment: I am currently trying that for all the files found in my folder, and I get strange errors in return, so I feel like something else is also missing.  The thing I am trying to run btw is in here, https://github.com/Bulat-Ziganshin/FA
Could you potentially try it yourself with those files?